# Alarm's notification only trigger in background

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating an alarm application ,in that i have created notification that display message and play sound. But now its work only in background,i have to minimize my application to trigger my notification,if my app is open then notification does not show.

code for notification are:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dateTimePiker.date = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.alertBody = @"Wake up";
    notification.soundName = @"ma.mp3";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (IBAction)SetAlarmBtnTapped:(id)sender {

    .....
    .....
    [self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:dateTimePiker.date];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` on your app delegate

from the docs:

> If the application is running in the foreground, there is no alert,
>   badging, or sound; instead, the
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method is called if the
>   delegate implements it.

Comment: you will have to play a sound yourself but i'm not sure if you have access to the system sounds, sorry

Comment: NO,thats not what i am saying, exactly i want that when user click on alarm than system alarm will open and set alarm in system alarm.

Comment: ah ok, I don't know how to do that, most alarm type apps use their own notification so i would guess that that is not possible but I'm not sure of that